# Observe UIImage with KVO?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, uiimage, key-value-observing

My model object has a **`UIImage *iconImg`** that is often updated asynchronously.  I want to allow instances of other classes to observe any changes to **`myModel.iconImg`** elegantly.  Right now, my asynchronous image fetch class takes a **`UIImage**`** (yes, ugly, but it's working).  The problem, however, is that messing with the UIImage via pointers bypasses any KVO I might have enjoyed using properties, so I have to use NSNotification which I'm not a big fan of.  Here are the main requirements:

1. I want to be able to load *iconImg* even when no views are ready to display it (ie no UIImageView is ready)
2. Ideally, only the instances that have elected to observe the specific **`myModel.iconImg`** instance will be made aware of changes (unlike with Notifications where I currently have to filter)
3. I have several model classes with **`iconImg`** properties that all need to work this way, not just one
4. I can change my image fetcher class if necessary (here's current signature):

   `+ (BOOL)asyncImageFetch:(UIImage**)anImagePtr withURL:(NSURL*)aUrl;`

Not sure how clear that is, so let me know if I can elaborate on anything.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Can you elaborate on point 1.  I don't see a question/problem in that statement.  What is stopping you loading it into a uiimage before a uiimageview is ready?

Comment: Nothing is stopping me.  That was just to point out that I can't pass a UIImageView* to the image fetcher and then observe imageView.image.

Comment: FYI- I'm currently attempting to integrate SDWebImage (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to provide this. So far, it's looking very promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking with similar requirements, take a look at SDWebImage (looks like Olivier Poitrey is the original author).  Github repository here: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.

I've been using it and it's very nice.